# How do I animate a UserControl along a Cubic Bezier Curve in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to animate a `UserControl` along a `Cubic Bezier Curve`.
This is the path I want the `UserControl` to be following:

```
<Path Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M100,500 C275,200 825,200 1100,500" />
```

This is the code I have tried to use, but I have only found a way to animate along a straight line:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MyAnimation">            
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ObjectTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:5">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1100" KeyTime="0:0:5"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ObjectTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:5">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="500" KeyTime="0:0:5"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

The only thing I have found that is talking about Bezier Curves is `SplineDoubleKeyFrame`. However, I can not get this to work even close to what I am looking for.

I have done this before in WPF by using `MatrixAnimationUsingPath` and `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` but these classes are not available in `UWP`. How do I animate a UserObject along a Path in UWP?

**EDIT:**
This is the code I have used for `SplineDoubleKeyFrame`:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MyAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ObjectTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:5">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="1100" KeyTime="0:0:5" KeySpline="0.25,0.0 0.75,0.0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ObjectTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:5">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="500" KeyTime="0:0:5" KeySpline="0.0,0.4 0.0,0.4"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

This is however only moving in a horizontal line at decreasing speed. I do not understand what the value for `KeySpline` should be.

Comment: @JustinXL may help you in this

Comment: The value for `KeySpline` is your Bezier Control Points. i.e. KeySpline="c1.x, c1.y, c2.x, c2.y". Above what you have created is the following curve: http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,.4,0,.4 (which initial starts very fast then decelerates to a constant speed). I am not sure why your y-direction is not working, unless the value 500 is the initial value and hence is trying to animate from 500 to 500.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned in the question about it but the only way without creating the bezier reducing function yourself is via `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` using `SplineDoubleKeyFrame`.

In the MSDN docs there's a good example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/key-frame-and-easing-function-animations

You'll want an initial key frame - so a basic linear key frame at time = 0 and value = x to set the initial value.

Then a `SplineDoubleKeyFrame` with the bezier control points, value at your final value and time at your ending time

Can you post the code you've tried and what was wrong with the result?

Comment: I have now added code for SplineDoubleKeyFrame. So, you are saying i should combine both LinearDoubleKeyFrame and SplineDoubleKeyFrame in order to get the result I want? I will try this and see if I get something to work